# What is the meaning of the Defense Minister's comments on motherhood?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In the *Fiat Voluntas Tua* section of *A Canticle for Leibowitz* the narrative around the increase in nuclear tension is partially told via the news conferences of the Defense Minister, Lord Ragelle.

At the end of these conferences, he is asked questions about motherhood by one of the reporters. He mentions that he is not in favour of motherhood.

**Is there any explanation on what the meaning of these sections are?**

> Lady Reporter: Are you in favour of Motherhood, Lord Ragelle?
>
> Defense Minister: I am sternly opposed to it, Madam. It exerts a malign influence on youth, particularly upon young recruits. The military services would have superior soldiers if our fighting men had not been corrupted by Motherhood.
>
> Lady Reporter: May we quote you on that?
>
> Defense Minister: Certainly, Madam - but only in my obituary not sooner.

And in a later section

> Lady Reporter: How is your abiding faith in Motherhood today, Lord Ragelle?
>
> Defense Minister: I hope Motherhood has at least as much abiding faith in me as I have in Motherhood.
>
> Lady Reporter: You deserve at least that much, I'm sure.

The [NPR Audio production](https://archive.org/details/NPRPresentsACANTICLEFORLIEBOWITZIn15Parts) of the book, plays these sections with laughter as if it is a non-serious question, but this is not evident within the original narrative.

Comment: Are you aware of the expression "Motherhood and apple pie"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typically politicians  can be relied on to support [motherhood](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/motherhood_statement); it's a bland inoffensive assertion.

Since the minister has already been making bland statements about the prospects of war, the Lady Reporter is being ironic by asking him such an easy question. The minister builds on her joke by feigning to oppose motherhood - but he doesn't want his joke broadcast until after he's dead (he presumably suspects that the voters wouldn't appreciate the humor).

Later, as the war crisis gets worse, the Lady Reporter asks about motherhood again, in effect asking if she'll get a more honest answer about the war this time.